ibuffer: after killing buffer (key x), cursor move up. Should be down
Might be a minor issue but it's really annoying to me.  If I'm in ibuffer and kill a buffer with x (ibuffer-do-kill-on-deletion-marks), the cursor moves to the line that was above the killed buffer.  I think this makes no sense and it should move to the next buffer (down the list).  I'm not great at elisp but looked at the code for it:
(define-ibuffer-op ibuffer-do-kill-on-deletion-marks ()
  "Kill buffers marked for deletion as with `kill-this-buffer'."
  (:opstring "killed"
   :active-opstring "kill"
   :dangerous t
   :complex t
   :mark :deletion
   :modifier-p t)
  (if (kill-buffer buf)
      'kill
    nil))

I can't see anything there to alter the behavior so I'm pretty sure this is beyond my knowledge.
Thanks for any help or pointers.

You might prefer to use d to mark the buffer(s) to be deleted and x to execute the deletion(s).

Thanks. I do that sometimes.  But it's very frustrating that d (buffer-mark-for-delete) moves the cursor down while x (ibuffer-do-kill-on-deletion-marks) moves the cursor up!
